# set_include_path() not working with relative require()

Tags: php

I am "requiring" a file that has a require() call of its own. But calling set_include_path() is not working with a relative path in require(). Unfortunately I have no control over the code file being required.

**C:/myapp/index.php** - My code

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . ';C:/app/subfolder');
require('C:/app/subfolder/index.php');
```

**C:/app/subfolder/index.php** - Third party code (no control)

```
require('../config.php'); // Require file located at C:/app/config.php
```

The result:

**Failed opening required '../config.php' (include_path='.;C:/app/subfolder')**

This does not work, even though C:/app/subfolder is in the include path. I would expect ../config.php to be C:/app/subfolder/../config.php. Perhaps I am not doing it correctly.

In this case C:/app/subfolder/index.php was originally never meant to be included into another PHP file. However, I am building code in front of it, and I want C:/app/subfolder/index.php to still be able to require/include files as if it never left its location.

I have read that using dirname() or __DIR__ fixes the relative path issue in require(), **but I cannot change the code in C:/app/subfolder/index.php**.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: `set_include_path()` or `get_include_path()` does not work like this. You can use relative path `require_once('subfolder/index.php');` instead.

Comment: Have you tried just: `set_include_path('C:/app/subfolder');` ?

Comment: are you sure `config.php` exists in `C:/app` directory ? include_path checks for relative path, so if the file is not present in `C:/app` it will definitely fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem as nothing to do with `set_include_path()` *scope*. Your fatal error shows actual `include_path` too, in which you can see your added path.

The problem is that the `../` call doesn't look at `include_path`, but at current working directory. This can be hard to understand calling the script via HTTP URL, but is more clear if you can call the script via commandline.

If you write this script at `/usr/angelina/myproject/subfolder/index.php` (note: in this explanatory example I will use Unix filePath/commands):

```
set_include_path( '/usr/angelina/myproject/subfolder' );
require '../config.php';
```

Then, in terminal, you write:

```
cd /usr/angelina/myproject/subfolder
php index.php
```

the script will be executed fine. But if you write:

```
cd /usr/angelina/myproject
php subfolder/index.php
```

the script will fails, **even if include path is set inside the same script you call.**

Above example to explain that your problem is not the include path, but the current working directory. To solve your issue, you have to change current directory with `chdir()`.

So, in `C:/myapp/index.php` you have to write:

```
chdir( 'C:/app/subfolder' );
require 'C:/app/subfolder/index.php';
```

And your script will works (or, at least: on my side it worked...)

Answer (score 0):

By using PHP's `eval()` function mixed with `file_get_contents()` and `str_replace()` you can achieve this:

```
<?php
$index = file_get_contents("C:/app/subfolder/index.php");

if (substr($index, 0, 5) == "<?php") $index = trim(substr($index, 5));

elseif (substr($index, 0, 2) == "<?") $index = trim(substr($index, 2));

if (substr($index, -2) == "?>") $index = trim(substr($index, 0, -2));

$index = str_replace("require('../config.php');", "require('C:/app/config.php');", $index);

eval($index);
?>
```

**What's happening?**

The eval function in PHP takes any code provided to it as a string and executes it. What's happening above is after using `str_replace()` to change the required path, `eval()` is being passed the content of the file `"C:/app/subfolder/index.php"` as a string with PHP opening and closing tags removed to avoid error. The result is PHP will execute whatever code you pass to it with the desired changes performed before execution.

Comment: I thought about doing this, but it doesn't seem like a stable solution, especially since the codebase has thousands of files, and not every file follows the same conventions.

Comment: @Joe Valid point. This is just the first thing that came to mind when I read over your question. Good luck.